# How to use TFS with Visual Studio without Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I'm looking at the MSDN subscription comparison (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx) and am a bit confused.  Regarding VS2010 Premium and Ultimate: what is the difference between the two?  Both offer TFS but only Ultimate comes with Team Explorer.  Can you use TFS without Team Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimate comes with Team Explorer ["Eaglestone"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3c9454e0-523a-4ee1-b436-5c6fc2110b34) - an eclipse plugin. All of the versions offering TFS come with the visual studio Team Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a bit outdated now so here is an update and some context: Team Explorer is the rich client for Team Foundation Server.  All Visual Studio 2010 (and later) editions come with Team Explorer built in. For previous versions of Visual Studio (2005 and 2008) it came as a seperate install.  You can still download it for free from the Microsoft website and install it even if you don't have Visual Studio installed.  Team Explorer "Eaglestone" is now branded as Team Explorer Everywhere;  it is an equivalent rich client, but instead of running as a plug-in to Visual Studio, it is a plug-in for Eclipse.  There used to be a seperate license fee for Team Explorer Everywhere, but it is now available for free.